# How to add copied dictionaries to array in Javascript?

Tags: reactjs

I have `function` named **"createdAtRefine"** to change items' createdAt from  milliseconds to MM/DD below.

```
 const createdAtRefine = (datasum) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < datasum.length; ++i) {
      datasum[i].createdAt = `${
        new Date(parseInt(datasum[i].createdAt)).getMonth() + 1
      }/${new Date(parseInt(datasum[i].createdAt)).getDate()}`;
    }
    return datasum;
  };
```

And I added several dictionary arrays to dataSumArray below.

datasumArray was set [] empty array.

```
  datasumArray.push(
    ...feedData.seeAdminAllFeeds,
    ...poemData.seeAdminAllPoems,
    ...fpLikesData.seeAdminAllLikes,
    ...fpCommentsData.seeAdminAllComments,
    ...pedometerData.seeAdminAllPedometers
  );
```

feedData.seeAdminAllFeeds looks like below.

-> [{__typename: 'Feed', id: '3', **createdAt: '18382034'**}, {__typename: 'Feed', id: '3', **createdAt: '18382034'**}]

Once all these dictionaries were added to one array I need to change createdAt from milliseconds to 'MM/DD' with above "createdAtRefind" function.

So i run below code.

```
  let createdAtRefind = createdAtRefine(datasumArray);
```

Then outcome is good, it change to
-> [{__typename: 'Feed', id: '3', **createdAt: '10/8'**}, {__typename: 'Feed', id: '3', **createdAt: '10/8'**}]

But Problem is I need to call all this function at first with `useEffect` like below.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (
      feedData !== undefined &&
      feedData !== null &&
      poemData !== undefined &&
      poemData !== null &&
      fpLikesData !== undefined &&
      (fpLikesData !== null) & (fpCommentsData !== undefined) &&
      fpCommentsData !== null &&
      pedometerData !== undefined &&
      pedometerData !== null
    ) {
      datasumArray.push(
        ...feedData.seeAdminAllFeeds,
        ...poemData.seeAdminAllPoems,
        ...fpLikesData.seeAdminAllLikes,
        ...fpCommentsData.seeAdminAllComments,
        ...pedometerData.seeAdminAllPedometers
      );
      let createdAtRefind = createdAtRefine(datasumArray);
      setDatasum(createdAtRefind);
    }
  }, [feedData, poemData, fpLikesData, fpCommentsData, pedometerData]);
```

When I first call this function, it works great.

But if I go to another screen and go back to this screen, `**createdAtRefind**` becomes all createdAt as '1/1'.

-> [{__typename: 'Feed', id: '3', **createdAt: '1/1'**}, {__typename: 'Feed', id: '3', **createdAt: '1/1'**}]

The reason is when I run "createdAtRefine" function, it change the initial data of `feedData.seeAdminAllFeeds`.

So initial data becomes

-> [{__typename: 'Feed', id: '3', **createdAt: '10/8'**}, {__typename: 'Feed', id: '3', **createdAt: '10/8'**}]

And so I run two times createdAtRefind function, so it becomes '1/1'..

I want to run this createdAtRefind function just once when this data comes regardless of screen change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mutating your objects inside the `dataSum` array. It's best practice in JS, especially in React to avoid mutation. You're getting `1/1` because `new Date(parseInt("10/8")).getMonth() + 1` gives you the number `1`.

What you can do is use `map`

```js
 const createdAtRefine = (datasum) => {
    return datasum.map((data) => ({
        ...data, // Spread data into new object
        createdAt = `${new Date(parseInt(datasum[i].createdAt)).getMonth() + 1}/${new Date(parseInt(datasum[i].createdAt)).getDate()}`
    }))
  };
```

Here for each dataSum element I create a new objects with the same keys and values as the original object except for `createdAt`.

If you're planning on displaying this createdAt date another way to go would be to keep the original `datasum` array with `createdAt` in ms and convert only when displaying the date